# Get Web Permissions for Specific User using SharePoint 2010 CSOM

Tags: permissions, csom

I need to check If Specific User has Permissions to Web. 
 I cannot find any way to do it in **SharePoint 2010** **Client Object Model**.

I need an alternative of *SPWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions(string userLoginName, SPBasePermissions permissions)* which is also accepted login name since client object model has this method only to check **current user permissions**. Beginning with SharePoint 2013 there is a method *Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions(userLoginName)* but this is not the case since it doesn't work in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

In the client object model you can check this property **GetUserEffectivePermissions**

```
string userName="UserLoginName"
ClientResult<BasePermissions> info = site.Web.GetUserEffectivePermissions(userName);

     //info.RoleAssignments is not recognized
     foreach (SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment in info.RoleAssignments)
     {
          //do further coding as per your need
     }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer but as I wrote this method is accessible only in SharePoint 2013. In SharePoint 2010 I receive an exception using this method.

Comment: Hi - I think GetUserEffectivePermissions and DoesUserHavePermissions are different. You can try with the GetUserEffectivePermissions

Comment: This method is not available in SharePoint 2010.